# Exec a shell command in Go

Tags: go, shellexecute

I'm looking to execute a shell command in Go and get the resulting output as a string in my program. I saw the [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Execute_a_system_command#Go) version:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "exec"

func main() {
  cmd, err := exec.Run("/bin/ls", []string{"/bin/ls"}, []string{}, "", exec.DevNull, exec.PassThrough, exec.PassThrough)
  if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }
  cmd.Close()
```

But this doesn't capture the actual standard out or err in a way that I can programatically access - those still print out to the regular stdout / stderr. I saw that using Pipe as the out or err could help elsewhere, but no example of how to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: This might be useful in some cases: https://github.com/mbrostami/gcron

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This answer does not represent the current state of the Go standard library. Please take a look at [@Lourenco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7786922) for an up-to-date method!**

---

Your example does not actually read the data from stdout. This works for me.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "exec"
   "os"
   "bytes"
   "io"
)

func main() {
    app := "/bin/ls"
    cmd, err := exec.Run(app, []string{app, "-l"}, nil, "", exec.DevNull, exec.Pipe, exec.Pipe)

    if (err != nil) {
       fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err.String())
       return
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&b, cmd.Stdout)
    fmt.Println(b.String())

    cmd.Close()
}
```

Comment: @ChrisBunch might consider switching the checkmark as a service to the community.

Comment: What is a package named "exec"? Why don't you use "os/exec" from the standard library? And keep using variables like `os.DevNull` instead of your `exec.DevNull`

Answer (score 253):

The package "exec" was [changed](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) a little bit. The following [code](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Command) worked for me.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    app := "echo"

    arg0 := "-e"
    arg1 := "Hello world"
    arg2 := "\n\tfrom"
    arg3 := "golang"

    cmd := exec.Command(app, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Print the output
    fmt.Println(string(stdout))
}
```

Comment: Now the import has to be like "os/exec" and I got an error with the err.String() but apart from that, it works. Thanks.

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban, thank you. I just upgrade the post as well as point links to the package and an example of use of exec.Command.

Comment: Is there a simple way to separate `stderr` from `stdout`. I see `CombinedOutput()`, and I see more complicated ways, but what I want is simply `out, errout, errcode = cmd.Output3()`.

Comment: @cdunn2001, (1) #easy you can set the `exec.Cmd.Stderr` before call `cmd.Output()` by [yourself](http://pastebin.com/TCRLsUSW) or (2) #hard you add [your function](http://pastebin.com/wDNXP4Y3) to golang ([$GOROOT/src/pkg/os/exec/exec.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/exec/exec.go)), recompile (cd $GOROOT/src && ./make.bash), [test it](http://pastebin.com/FTW2nsaX).

Comment: this is works for me !!! thank you. the `app` and the `arguments` must be separated

Comment: This doesn't work for wildcards i.e. `*`. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467153/golang-failed-exec-command-that-works-in-terminal) to see how to handle wildcards.

Answer (score 89):

None of the provided answers allow to separate `stdout` and `stderr` so I try another answer.

First you get all the info you need, if you look at the documentation of the `exec.Cmd` type in the `os/exec` package. Look here: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd

Especially the members `Stdin` and `Stdout`,`Stderr` where any `io.Reader` can be used to feed `stdin` of your newly created process and any `io.Writer` can be used to consume `stdout` and `stderr` of your command.

The function `Shellout` in the following programm will run your command and hand you its output and error output separatly as strings.

As the parameter value is executed as a shell command, sanitize
all external inputs used in the construction of the parameter
value.

Probably don't use it in this form in production.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

const ShellToUse = "bash"

func Shellout(command string) (string, string, error) {
    var stdout bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command(ShellToUse, "-c", command)
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    return stdout.String(), stderr.String(), err
}

func main() {
    out, errout, err := Shellout("ls -ltr")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("--- stdout ---")
    fmt.Println(out)
    fmt.Println("--- stderr ---")
    fmt.Println(errout)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, this should be at the top. Having the ability to have a Golang error, stdout, and stderr clearly separated is the best combination available in this post.

Comment: Fantastic answer 2

Comment: Using `Command("bash", "-c", blah)` somehow solved the problem I was having.

Comment: I like this helper function for when you have a string and just want to use it as a command. Maybe not the safest thing to run in prod (maybe that's why the std lib approach uses varargs, not `string`), but useful for quick stuff. The only change I would suggest would be to re-arrange the return types so that error is last, which would be the Go convention for returning errors. VS Code complained about this to me when I copy and pasted this in.

Comment: I always thought code snippets here on stackoverflow are just examples, you should alter as you see fit. But you are right in all regards.

Comment: I added a warning about inputs and changed `Shellout` so it returns error last.

Comment: You swapped the order of `err` and `out` in the line you call `Shellout`

Comment: @AmrSaber Thank you, didn't notice that! Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

```
// Wrap exec, with option to use bash shell

func Cmd(cmd string, shell bool) []byte {

    if shell {
        out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd).Output()
        if err != nil {
            panic("some error found")
        }
        return out
    } else {
        out, err := exec.Command(cmd).Output()
        if err != nil {
            panic("some error found")
        }
        return out
    }
}
```

you may try this .

Comment: Thanks qing this is a useful function for running miscellaneous commands via the shell, without having to split up all the args like in @Lourenco 's answer

Comment: Obviously this is no longer a cross-platform solution, but the question is specific to shell commands.

Comment: Note that if `shell` is `false`, arguments can't be passed to the command.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple function that will run your command and capture the error, stdout, and stderr for you to inspect. You can easily see anything that might go wrong or be reported back to you.

```
// RunCMD is a simple wrapper around terminal commands
func RunCMD(path string, args []string, debug bool) (out string, err error) {

    cmd := exec.Command(path, args...)

    var b []byte
    b, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
    out = string(b)

    if debug {
        fmt.Println(strings.Join(cmd.Args[:], " "))

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("RunCMD ERROR")
            fmt.Println(out)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

You can use it like this (Converting a media file):

```
args := []string{"-y", "-i", "movie.mp4", "movie_audio.mp3", "INVALID-ARG!"}
output, err := RunCMD("ffmpeg", args, true)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", output)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Result:", output)
}
```

I've used this with Go 1.2-1.7

Comment: This is actually great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want run long-running script **asynchronously** with execution progress, you may capture command output using `io.MultiWriter` and forward it to `stdout/stderr`:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

var stdoutBuf, stderrBuf bytes.Buffer

cmd := exec.Command("/some-command")

cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &stdoutBuf)
cmd.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, &stderrBuf)

err := cmd.Start()  // Starts command asynchronously

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err.Error())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "dir")
    output, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error executing command:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

Use the exec.Command function to create a new cmd process with the /C flag and the dir command as its argument
Capture output with output() method and print it.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
import (
    "github.com/go-cmd/cmd"
)

const DefaultTimeoutTime = "1m"

func RunCMD(name string, args ...string) (err error, stdout, stderr []string) {
    c := cmd.NewCmd(name, args...)
    s := <-c.Start()
    stdout = s.Stdout
    stderr = s.Stderr
    return
}
```

go test

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "gotest.tools/assert"
    "testing"
)

func TestRunCMD(t *testing.T) {
    err, stdout, stderr := RunCMD("kubectl", "get", "pod", "--context", "cluster")
    assert.Equal(t, nil, err)
    for _, out := range stdout {
        fmt.Println(out)
    }
    for _, err := range stderr {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the Rosetta example to work in my Windows Go. Finally I managed to go past the old format of the Subprocess with this command to start outfile in notepad in windows. The wait constant parameter mentioned in one manual did not exist so I just left out Wait as the user will close the program by themself or leave it open to reuse.

```
p, err := os.StartProcess(`c:\windows\system32\notepad.EXE`,
    []string{`c:\windows\system32\notepad.EXE`, outfile},
    &os.ProcAttr{Env: nil, Dir: "", Files:  []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr}})
```

You would change the os.Stdout.. to os.Pipe as previous answer

EDIT: I got it finally from godoc os Wait, that Wait has changed to method of and I succeeded to do:

```
   defer p.Wait(0)
```

Then I decided finally to put

```
   defer p.Release()
```

instead.