# golang failed exec command that works in terminal

Tags: go

I am getting an error when I try to use the `exec` package to run a `mv` command.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
cmd := exec.Command("mv", "./source-dir/*", "./dest-dir")
output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

cmd.Run()
```

err returns the following
`exit status 1`

output returns this `mv: rename ./source-dir/* to ./dest-dir/*: No such file or directory`

I can actually get the script to work when I change this line:

`cmd := exec.Command("mv", "./source-dir/*", "./dest-dir")`

to the following:

`cmd := exec.Command("mv", "./source-dir/file.txt", "./dest-dir")`

The command works and moves the file successfully but using the wildcard doesn't work. It appears that the asterisk isn't being used as a wildcard in the command. Why is that? Is there another way to use wildcards in GO? If not then how else would I be able to recursively move all files from the `source-dir` to the `dest-dir`?

Thanks

Comment: It only got one downvote, who knows why. I brought it back to 0.

Comment: @hobbs thanks. When I first looked at it, it was at -2

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you type the command at the shell, the shell takes `./source_dir/*` and replaces it with a list of all of the files that match, one per argument. The `mv` command sees a list of filenames, not a wildcard.

What you need to do is either do the same thing yourself (using [filepath.Glob](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) which returns a `[]string` of matching files), or to invoke the shell so that it can do the work (using `exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "mv ./source_dir/* ./dest_dir")`).

Comment: I will give that a try when I get home tonight